# What's wrong with my include path, when trying to run my Zend application?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I'm kinda riddled with my Zend application...I have a full application working on a different server which I developed with Zend framework and now I have to make some changes to the software. I have downloaded all the code from the server and done all necessary configurations to my belief, but still I get the following error from log-file:

```
==> error.log <==
[Fri Jan 11 10:49:53 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(Zend/Application.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/jonne/Koulu/exercise_project/ProjectFiles/languageTest/application/application.php on line 18
[Fri Jan 11 10:49:53 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path='/home/jonne/Koulu/exercise_project/ProjectFiles/languageTest/library:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/jonne/Koulu/exercise_project/ProjectFiles/languageTest/application/application.php on line 18

==> access.log <==
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2013:10:49:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 274 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0"
```

I'm riddled with this, because the include path seems right to me?...

In the path `/home/jonne/Koulu/exercise_project/ProjectFiles/languageTest/library`
I have two symlinks which point to locations:

```
Zend -> /home/jonne/Koulu/exercise_project/ZendFolder/Zend
ZendX -> /home/jonne/Koulu/exercise_project/ZendFolder/ZendX
```

Here is the content of both folders Zend and ZendX:

Zend:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 jonne jonne  4096 Jan 11 10:12 bin
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jonne jonne   928 Jun 13  2012 composer.json
drwxrwxrwx  3 jonne jonne  4096 Jan 11 10:12 demos
drwxrwxrwx  3 jonne jonne  4096 Jan 11 10:12 externals
drwxrwxrwx  5 jonne jonne  4096 Jan 11 10:12 extras
drwxrwxrwx  2 jonne jonne  4096 Jan 11 10:12 incubator
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jonne jonne  3438 Apr  7  2009 INSTALL.txt
drwxrwxrwx  3 jonne jonne  4096 Jan 11 10:12 library
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jonne jonne  1548 Jan  6  2010 LICENSE.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jonne jonne 12209 Jun 22  2012 README.txt
drwxrwxrwx  3 jonne jonne  4096 Jan 11 10:13 resources
drwxrwxrwx  2 jonne jonne  4096 Jan 11 10:12 src
drwxrwxrwx  4 jonne jonne  4096 Jan 11 10:12 tests
```

ZendX:

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 jonne jonne 4096 Jan 11 10:13 Application
drwxrwxrwx 3 jonne jonne 4096 Jan 11 10:13 Console
drwxrwxrwx 4 jonne jonne 4096 Jan 11 10:13 Db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jonne jonne 1137 Sep 17 11:38 Exception.php
drwxrwxrwx 5 jonne jonne 4096 Jan 11 10:13 JQuery
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jonne jonne 4958 Sep 17 11:38 JQuery.php
```

Here is the code from my application.php:

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'

);

$application->bootstrap()->run();
```

And here is the contents of application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
;resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "login"
;resources.frontController.defaultAction = "login"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.view = ""
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.layout.layout = "main"


[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Why does it still complain about file not found?!...

Thnx =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your 'Zend' symlink to point at:

```
Zend -> /home/jonne/Koulu/exercise_project/ZendFolder/Zend/library/Zend
```

The 'ZendX' one looks correct. ZF should be able to find `Zend/Application.php` on the include path, but your symlink points to the root of a ZF full download.

Comment: Yep! That did the trick! :) Funny...I didn't consider that, because I recalled it did work even by just symlinking to the Zend root-folder...guess I was wrong then =D Thank you again =)